# Unnecessary escape character warning when running 'npm start' with React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm running my React app with *npm start* and App compiles but i'm getting this warning in terminal:

> Line 24:  Unnecessary escape character:  \[  no-useless-escape

Here's the code it's referring to:

```
  validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  }
```

How do I address this warning?

Comment: add `//eslint-disable-next-line` or something on the line before the re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another slash `/` into your code like this

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. I also had success removing the "\" in locations where "\[" where together.